# Can I use commercial VPN service with optional Dedicated IP to Host a Website?

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, ip

Many commercial VPN service providers offer a new option called "Dedicated IP." While I understand the purpose is to get around geoblocks of streaming services and to defeat their VPN detection mechanism, I was wondering if anyone was successful in using the dedicated IP feature to host a website? In my scenario, I have a webserver behind ISP router. The ISP does not offer public IP. My idea is - I will install VPN client on that server, and somehow use VPN service's optional public IP purchase option to route traffic from my domain example.com to the IP address bought from the VPN provider.

Comment: That's an interesting concept that could work. The best place to start would be with the knowledge base and FAQs of the VPN provider that you use (or want to use).

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic, i dont think, that the VPN-Provider will support this scenario. Here would it be easier to use either a service like cloudflare or 2-3 other small servers which just act as a proxy to the real destination. (i.e. nextcup i.e. charges ~ 2.50 for the smallest, which is enough for a reverse proxy)